# What are the best practices for implementing encryption logic in iOS?

Tags: c#, ios, encryption, hash, salt

I'm trying to implement payment mechanism in iOS app. So i want send payment related details like card no, card holder name e.t.c. to our server(C#) with encryption for secure communication between mobile and server. Please suggest some good encryption and decryption techniques.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Use HTTPS. Set the server up to support TLS 1.2 and Perfect Forward Secrecy. On the client pin the certificate to prevent MITM attacks.

If you are saving full CC numnbers on the server you will need to be [PCI](https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org) compliant.

Comment: Thanks Zaph.
We are already using HTTPS and TLS 1.2 enabled server, Do you think this is sufficient for passing the card details to server from my mobile app.
or 
Do you recommend encryption (hashing + salting) of card details ? If so 
can you suggest best Encryption and Decryption frameworks and libraries which support iOS, android and C#.

Comment: I think so if you have pinned the server certificate in the client but I am not a PCI auditor.  You need to pin the server certificate to prevent MITM attacks. While MITM used to be difficult not that so many connections are WiFi they are relatively easy. One method is to imitate a free WiFi hotspot. But even at home it may not be that simple. Many devices will automatically choose a WiFi connection automatically, I had this happen at home when a neighbor installed an open WiFi access point, I eventually noticed that I was not connection through my WiFi and have since locked down my devices.

Comment: Thanks again, Zaph.

If the certificate is pinned in the client apps, wouldn’t that make them available for others to access by decompiling? Wouldn’t that be a security issue?

Or is there any Public/Private key mechanism involved/recommended to overcome the above?

Comment: [Certificate pinning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Public_Key_Pinning) means examining the certificate presented by the server and verifying that it is indeed from the correct server. The certificate holds the server public key, valid dates, and organization information including the Common Name and Organization, some subset of these are verified. An attacker may have a valid certificate but it will not be the correct one.

Comment: So with Certificate pinning only the authorised Server would be passed the info. But the Payment details(Card number etc.) would still be sent from client app  to server, in plain text without any encryption? How would this ensure security of the payment details from MITM?

Also how to ensure Perfect Forward Secrecy between client(iOS App) & server endpoint? Is there any encryption involved?

Or certificate pinning and encryption at client side would be sufficient?